# Python converting binary data to 64-bit floating point. "error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes"

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, binary

I am trying to convert a binary file with the hex representation:
4187D78400000000. This has a 64 bit floating point value (big-endian) of 50000000.

However when I try to unpack the structure using:

```
sample_freq = byte[8:16]
print(sample_freq)
sample_freq = struct.unpack('f', byte[8:16])
print(sample_freq)
```

I get the following error:

```
b'A\x87\xd7\x84\x00\x00\x00\x00'
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:XXXXX", line 32, in <module>
    sample_freq = struct.unpack('f', byte[8:16])

error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the character `f` to unpack the value, it will try to read a 32 bits float number. To decode a 64 bits value you should read it as a double using character `d`.
So this should be the correct way to do it:

```
sample_freq = byte[8:16]
print(sample_freq)
sample_freq = struct.unpack('d', byte[8:16])
print(sample_freq)
```